# Merge two tables and replicate rows using two date columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex, sql-insert

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_4 
(
    DATE_INI    DATE NOT NULL,
    DATE_FIN    DATE NOT NULL,
    TOT_CLIENT  NUMBER NOT NULL,
    LOCATOR NUMBER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_4 (DATE_INI, DATE_FIN, TOT_CLIENT, LOCATOR) 
VALUES (to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), to_date('19/9/26', 'RR/MM/DD'), 3, 758908);
INSERT INTO TABLE_4 (DATE_INI, DATE_FIN, TOT_CLIENT, LOCATOR) 
VALUES (to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), to_date('19/9/26', 'RR/MM/DD'), 2, 765590);

CREATE TABLE TABLE_5 
( 
    LOCATOR     NUMBER NOT NULL,
    DATE_CLIENT DATE NOT NULL,
    NAME        VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_5 (LOCATOR, DATE_CLIENT, NAME) 
VALUES (758908, to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), 'Maria');
INSERT INTO TABLE_5 (LOCATOR, DATE_CLIENT, NAME) 
VALUES (758908, to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), 'Luis');
INSERT INTO TABLE_5 (LOCATOR, DATE_CLIENT, NAME) 
VALUES (758908, to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), 'Pedro');
INSERT INTO TABLE_5 (LOCATOR, DATE_CLIENT, NAME) 
VALUES (765590, to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), 'Manuel');
INSERT INTO TABLE_5 (LOCATOR, DATE_CLIENT, NAME) 
VALUES (765590, to_date('19/9/23', 'RR/MM/DD'), 'Ana');

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TABLE_6  
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 2206 
NOCACHE ORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_6 
(
     ID NUMBER DEFAULT SEQ_TABLE_6.nextval  NOT NULL,
     ACTUAL_DATE    DATE NOT NULL,
     DATE_INI       DATE NOT NULL,
     DATE_FIN       DATE NOT NULL,
     LOCATOR        NUMBER NOT NULL,
     NAME           VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL
);
```

Is it possible to get this result?

[image]

The idea is:

1. Create rows based on date_ini and date_fin, create all dates that are between those columns. As you see on "actual_date" on table_6
2. Replicate the information that we have on table_5 per dates rows

Can somebody help me with this query?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive query:

```
insert into table_6(actual_date, date_ini, date_fin, locator, name) 
with cte (actual_date, date_ini, date_fin, locator, name) as (
    select t4.date_ini actual_date, t4.date_ini, t4.date_fin, t5.locator, t5.name
    from table_4 t4
    inner join table_5 t5 on t5.date_client = t4.date_ini and t5.locator = t4.locator
    union all
    select actual_date + 1, date_ini, date_fin, locator, name
    from cte
    where actual_date < date_fin
)
select * from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=16e852c827c9974dbb6d1a90022787b6)**:

```
  ID | ACTUAL_DATE | DATE_INI  | DATE_FIN  | LOCATOR | NAME  
---: | :---------- | :-------- | :-------- | ------: | :-----
2206 | 23-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Maria 
2207 | 23-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Luis  
2208 | 23-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Pedro 
2209 | 23-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Manuel
2210 | 23-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Ana   
2211 | 24-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Maria 
2212 | 24-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Luis  
2213 | 24-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Pedro 
2214 | 24-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Manuel
2215 | 24-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Ana   
2216 | 25-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Maria 
2217 | 25-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Luis  
2218 | 25-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Pedro 
2219 | 25-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Manuel
2220 | 25-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Ana   
2221 | 26-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Maria 
2222 | 26-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Luis  
2223 | 26-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  758908 | Pedro 
2224 | 26-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Manuel
2225 | 26-SEP-19   | 23-SEP-19 | 26-SEP-19 |  765590 | Ana
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with subquery factoring like below

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT date_ini + column_value - 1 AS dates,
                    date_ini,
                    date_fin,
                    tot_client,
                    locator
             FROM   table_4
                    cross join TABLE(Cast(MULTISET (SELECT LEVEL
                                              FROM   dual
                                              CONNECT BY date_ini + LEVEL <=
                                                         date_fin + 1
                                                   )
                                          AS
         sys.ODCINUMBERLIST))),
         data1
         AS (SELECT dates,
                    date_ini,
                    date_fin,
                    locator
             FROM   data
             ORDER  BY dates,
                       date_ini,
                       date_fin,
                       locator)
    SELECT d1.*,
           t5.name
    FROM   data1 d1,
           table_5 t5
    WHERE  d1.locator = t5.locator 
    and d1.date_ini=t5.date_client
```

Output below

```
        DATES   DATE_INI    DATE_FIN    LOCATOR NAME
    23-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Pedro
    23-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Maria
    23-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Luis
    23-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Manuel
    23-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Ana
    24-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Pedro
    24-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Luis
    24-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Maria
    24-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Ana
    24-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Manuel
    25-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Maria
    25-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Luis
    25-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Pedro
    25-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Ana
    25-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Manuel
    26-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Maria
    26-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Luis
    26-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   758908  Pedro
    26-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Ana
    26-SEP-19   23-SEP-19   26-SEP-19   765590  Manuel
```